# How do I safely run a jq command with a | (pipe) character?

Tags: json, linux, bash, go, jq

I have program that lets users parse JSON data with jq. I am shelling out to jq rather than using a library because the ones I've found have weird and inconsistent behaviour. The problem I have is that jq often has `|` (pipe) characters and, that could potentially let users run non-jq commands. e.g.:

`jq . | rm file.txt`

How do I safely let users run this?

Right now, I invoke it as this in Go (where file.txt contains the raw json):

```
cmd = exec.Command("bash", "-c", fmt.Sprintf("cat file.txt | %s", cmd))
```

Thanks!

EDIT:
As pointed out several times, this question isn't about piping commands together. It is about how to safely execute a jq command that has pipes in it. I don't want users to do this: curl 'api.icndb.com/jokes/random/3' | jq -r '.value[] | .joke | rm file.txt'. Please re-open.

Comment: You need to properly quote whatever you pass to jq.  How exactly are you invoking `jq`?  How are you handling the user string?  Details matter.

Comment: Oh, ok. I've edited but if there is a better way please suggest!

Comment: ok. The backticks can be replaced with double quotes in this case. I didn't tag as Go since the answer doesn't have to be Go...the part I'm interested in is the command line command I should run.

Comment: Why can't you use the https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/ package from go standard library?

Comment: The users using the end service are familiar with jq. They need to extract the element(s) they want from the JSON.

Comment: This causes problems: `curl 'http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/3' | jq -r '.value[] | .joke'`

Comment: I chose not to use https://github.com/itchyny/gojq because they don't dump the raw output of the jq command. Instead, you have to iterate through each of the jokes. This presents a problem since the jq command is not fixed and I have to handle a whole bunch of edge cases.

Comment: The [`cat` is useless.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) I guess you are using it as a placeholder, but if you can avoid invoking a shell at all, you can significantly simplify the problem.

Comment: This question isn't about piping commands together. It is about how to safely execute a jq command that has pipes in it. I don't want users to do this: curl 'http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/3' | jq -r '.value[] | .joke | rm file.txt'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use io.Pipe() which basically creates a synchronous in-memory pipe and it can be used to connect code expecting an io.Reader with code expecting an io.Writer. For instance, if you have a json content like this:

```
{
  "fruits": [
    "apples",
    "oranges",
    "pears"
  ]
}
```

You can try something like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    c1 := exec.Command("cat", "/home/fruits.json")
    c2 := exec.Command("jq", ".fruits[0:2]")

    r, w := io.Pipe()
    c1.Stdout = w
    c2.Stdin = r

    var b2 bytes.Buffer
    c2.Stdout = &b2

    c1.Start()
    c2.Start()
    c1.Wait()
    w.Close()
    c2.Wait()
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &b2)
}
```

It will gives you something like this:

```
[
  "apples",
  "oranges"
]
```

Even though you can pipe several commands like this, I would strongly recommend to use the [json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package from standard library to Marshal and Unmarshal JSON.

Comment: The question was how to do it safely. This could potentially cause problems: curl 'http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/3' | jq -r '.value[] | .joke | rm file.txt'

Comment: @user_78361084, no, it can't (*), because no shell is involved in the above code. The argument to jq is only interpreted by jq itself, nothing else. * This is assuming you don't let the client control the filename.